# How to switch from TTY to KDE in Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, xorg, kde, console

I had installed Oracle Linux. While installing I had selected KDE for the desktop.
After finishing I assumed that I could login to KDE Desktop, but I got a TTY.

It asked for login and I gave root and for password entered what I had given while installing.

The thing is I want to go to KDE desktop from TTY. I got after logging in:

```
[root@techsunil ~]#
```

How can I switch to desktop of KDE?

Comment: can I ask what a reason to run oracle linux on desktop ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of things you need to be aware of.
What is the current run level ? 3 or 5?
Check it by

> cat /etc/inittab | grep id\:

If it's 3 then change it to 5 by editing the file and restart or issue on the command line `init 5`.

If you want to have the GUI login screen, make sure you have KDM or GDM installed run

> rpm -q kdm

If this returns no packages, you'll have to install it (but that should have been taken care of by installing KDE).

Answer (score -1):

You need to install and setup KDM. This is easiest way.